# How can this derivative with respect to an element of an inverse covariance matrix be computed?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Let the following function be defined: $$P_3(C) = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{2\pi} \arcsin\left( \frac{C_{13}}{\sqrt{C_{11} C_{33}}} \right),$$
where C is a 3x3 covariance matrix.

Now we need to compute $\partial P_3(C) / \partial C_{23}^{-1}$
where $C_{23}^{-1}$ is an element of the inverse of $C$ and hence defined as:
$$
C_{23}^{-1}=\frac{C_{12} C_{13}-C_{11} C_{23}}{-C_{33} C_{12}^2+2 C_{13} C_{23} C_{12}-C_{11} C_{23}^2-C_{13}^2 C_{22}+C_{11} C_{22} C_{33}}\, .
$$
How would one go about computing the inner derivative of $\partial P_3(C) / \partial C_{23}^{-1}$, namely:
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial C_{23}^{-1}} \left( \frac{C_{13}}{\sqrt{C_{11} C_{33}}} \right)\, .
$$
Thanks in advance for your help.